# Oracle SQL how many days has passed since previous order

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem how to calculate the days how many days has passed since previous order.

My code:

```
select
    order_id,
    order_date
from 
    oe.orders
where customer_id = 838
order by
    order_date desc
```

The order_id and order_date are like below:

1. order_id = 1920 & order_date= 25-MAR-19 15.45.38.000000000
2. order_id = 1618 & order_date= 08-FEB-19 12.51.39.000000000
3. order_id = 1592 & order_date= 04-FEB-19 07.35.46.000000000
   ...

I am new user of sql and no idea how to do it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What data type is the column `order_date`?

Comment: You get the date of the previous order with `LAG(order_date) OVER (ORDER BY order_date)`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner the column order_date is timestamp with local time zone e.g. 25-MAR-19 15.45.38.000000000

Comment: I used this option: order_date - lag(order_date) over (order by order_id). It worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want the differences in days (just the date part) then:

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select 1 "ID", To_Date('25-MAR-19 15.45.38', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') "A_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ID", To_Date('08-FEB-19 12.51.39', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') "A_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "ID", To_Date('04-FEB-19 07.35.46', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') "A_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 4 "ID", To_Date('28-JAN-19 12.13.10', 'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') "A_DATE" From Dual 
        )

Select
    ID "ID",
    TRUNC(A_DATE, 'dd') - TRUNC(Nvl(First_Value(A_DATE) OVER (Order By ID Rows Between 1 Preceding And Current Row), A_DATE), 'dd') "DAYS_DIFF"
From
    tbl
```

| ID | DAYS_DIFF |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | -45 |
| 3 | -4 |
| 4 | -7 |

OR ...

```sql
Select
    ID "ID",
    TRUNC(A_DATE, 'dd') - TRUNC(Nvl(Last_Value(A_DATE) OVER (Order By ID Rows Between Current Row And 1 Following ), A_DATE), 'dd') "DAYS_DIFF"
From
    tbl
Order By TRUNC(A_DATE, 'dd')
```

... result

| ID | DAYS_DIFF |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 0 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 45 |

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(ORDER_ID, ORDER_DATE) AS
SELECT 3,  TIMESTAMP'2022-10-31 09:54:48' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,  TIMESTAMP'2022-10-17 19:04:44' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,  TIMESTAMP'2022-10-08 14:44:23' FROM DUAL 

SELECT order_id, order_date,
order_date - LAG(order_date) OVER (ORDER BY order_id) AS diff
FROM   orders;

ORDER_ID    ORDER_DATE    DIFF
1    08-OCT-22 02.44.23.000000 PM     - 
2    17-OCT-22 07.04.44.000000 PM    +000000009 04:20:21.000000000
3    31-OCT-22 09.54.48.000000 AM    +000000013 14:50:04.000000000
```